Have you ever heard, in a buyout, common shareholders (not insiders) being issued shares restricted for two years?
I have shares in a company which was bought out by another company issuing shares to stockholders. The insiders were issued a larger percentage of shares than they had originally owned. The common shareholders got a lesser percentage and were issued common stock restricted for two years. Normally, it is insiders (Executives, Officers, Employees who are not yet vested, and shareholders owning more than 10% of the stock) who might get restricted shares. Rarely, common stock might be restricted for six months, or even rarer, one year, but I have never heard of a two year restriction.
I believe the only reason for the acquisition is because the former company couldn't get any accounting firm to sign off on an audit. The "buyer" was not designated as a shell company, but I could not find any commerce in the last few years. So, getting a defunct company to buy them gives them a fresh start. There are new names for the executive team in the corporate filings, but I am sure the former CEO and executives are still in charge.
There was no shareholder vote about any of this because the CEO of the "bought" company was the sole majority owner.(It is questionable how he acquired that many shares, as his number of shares kept going up without any SEC filings showing he bought shares, or any Board notes authorizing giving him that many shares.)
Is there anything the shareholders can do? Can anyone recommend an attorney that can litigate in Florida?

I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for attorney recommendations and legal advice. You'll need to find attorney references somewhere else, this forum is not for recommendations.

In general, shareholders who are similarly situated have to be treated similarly. The majority shareholder can't decide that the minority shareholders shouldn't have the same rights that he has. The term you're looking for is "shareholder derivative action", a lawsuit against the corporation to force it to treat its shareholders fairly. There's a long history of majority shareholders deciding that they're special and don't have to play fair, and the courts will often step in to enforce fairness. See, for example, Elon Musk's recent escapades; the Delaware chancery court rejected his $56 billion pay package, despite shareholder approval.
